# confusion on variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, css

This is a simple example of stacking text elements.

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Program 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex2.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="box" id="para1" onmouseover="display('para1');">
        This is a paragraph.
    </p>
    <p class="box" id="para2" onmouseover="display('para2');">
        This is a paragraph.
    </p>
    <p class="box" id="para3" onmouseover="display('para3');">
        This is a paragraph.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
    .box {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 500px;
        position: absolute;
    }

    #para1 {
        font-size: 20pt;
        color: white;
        background: red;
        top: 150px;
        left: 150px;
    }

    #para2 {
        font-size: 20pt;
        color: white;
        background: blue;
        top: 200px;
        left: 200px;
    }

    #para3 {
        font-size: 20pt;
        color: white;
        background: green;
        top: 250px;
        left: 250px;
    }
```

js:

```
var defaultTop = 'para3';

function display(select)
{

    newTop = document.getElementById(select)
    oldTop = document.getElementById(defaultTop);

    oldTop.style.zIndex = "0";
    newTop.style.zIndex = "10";

    defaultTop = select;
}
```

When I place `var defaultTop = 'para3';` inside a function, only the `para2` and `para3` are displayed respectively as I move the mouse over, but not `para1`. But when I place `var defaultTop = 'para3';` outside the function all the para are displayed respectively. Why?

Comment: Try to read on:
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript/500459#500459
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: Because the function has a different scope that the global program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you place the `defaultTop` inside the function, the variable only exists whilst the function is being executed. Once the function execution stops, the value of the variable (and the variable itself) is lost.

Each time you're calling `display()`, the variable `defaultTop` is being defined, initialized, then lost.

However, when you define it outside the function, it persists through invocations, and holds it's value persistently.

This is because of *scope*. Variables last as long as their scope does. Function scope lasts as long as the function executes (more technically, for the duration of the closure, but that isn't relevant in this scenario). Global scope lasts for the duration of the program.